# Buscar cadena dentro de un campo de texto, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, búsquedas

Tengo el siguiente problema: necesito hallar una subcadena exacta **que comienza y termina con números** dentro de un campo de texto.

La query de momento es:

```
SELECT * (...)    

FROM dominio AS Dom, ampliatoria AS Amp, (...) 

WHERE (...)
AND Amp.descripcion ILIKE '%' || Dom.dom_descripcion || '%';
```

El campo `Dom.dom_descripcion` posee cadenas que tienen la forma `{números + "-" + números}` ó `{números + "-" + números + "/" + números}`. Por ejemplo algunos casos serían: "1-1234" ó "5-678/9", etc.

El campo `Amp.descripcion` posee cadenas con texto que incluyen alguna de las formas anteriores. Puede contener texto antes o después de los números.

El problema es que cuando corro la consulta se hallan coincidencias erróneas del tipo "1-123" con "11-1234", "4-789/1" con "14-789/11", etc...

---

Necesitaría conocer alguna forma de hallar si el campo `Amp.descripcion` ***contiene exactamente*** la cadena que trae el campo `Dom.dom_descripcion`.

Es decir, si por ejemplo el campo **descripcion** = "bla bla 1-1234 y 2-345/6 bla bla", debería coincidir con algún campo "dom_descripcion" = "1-1234" ó "2-345/6".

---

Uso PostgreSQL 9.0 con pgAdmin III. No puedo cambiar la versión ni gestor utilizado.

Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Proporciona mas ejemplos de cadenas exactas. No me queda claro si una cadena como AA1-1234B es exacta para 1-1234 o no. O, ¿las cadenas exactas siempre tienen espacio antes y despues como AA 1-1234 B ?

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar! Los campos con las cadenas "objetivo" que lleven además otros caracteres deberían tener un espacio antes y después del resto de caracteres ("AA 1-123 B"). Nótese el "deberían", pienso que también es posible que existan casos como "AA1-123B" donde la cadena correcta solo es "1-123".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tengo claro las cadenas que califican como exactas, así que solo veo dos situaciones:

1. Las cadenas son exactas completamente. Es decir, los campos `amp.descripcion` y `dom.dom_descripcion` tienen exactamente el mismo valor.
2. Las cadenas de amp.descripcion pueden contener cualquier caracter antes y despues de el texto deseado, excepto números. Por ejemplo AA1-23B coincide con 1-23 pero 11-231 no coincide con 1-23.

Si puedes agregar mas validaciones sería perfecto. Mientras tanto, asumiendo únicamente las dos validaciones anteriores:

```
create table ampliatoria(
descripcion varchar(100) not null
);

create table dominio(
dom_descripcion varchar(100) not null
);


insert into ampliatoria values ('11-1234');
insert into ampliatoria values ('111-12344');
insert into ampliatoria values ('1-1234');
insert into ampliatoria values ('AA5-55B');
insert into ampliatoria values ('4-789/1');

insert into dominio values ('5-55');
insert into dominio values ('1-123');
insert into dominio values ('1-1234');
insert into dominio values ('4-789/1');
```

Usando like entre ambos campos:

```
select *
from ampliatoria amp, dominio dom
where  amp.descripcion like '%' || dom.dom_descripcion || '%'
```

Obtenemos los siguientes resultados correctos y erróneos:

```
descripcion     dom_descripcion
11-1234         1-123
11-1234         1-1234
111-12344       1-123
111-12344       1-1234
1-1234          1-123
1-1234          1-1234
AA5-55B         5-55
4-789/1         4-789/1
```

Tendremos que evitar los números antes y después de la cadena buscada. En postgresql no podemos usar listas de caracteres como [a-z] con `LIKE` pero si los podemos utilizar con **`SIMILAR`**. Definimos una lista de los numeros como [0-9] y utilizamos el caracter ^ para indicar que no incluya ningun caracter de la lista, así [^0-9]. Indicamos que no se encuentre antes ni después de la cadena buscada:

```
select *
from ampliatoria amp, dominio dom
where  amp.descripcion similar to '%[^0-9]' || dom.dom_descripcion || '[^0-9]%'
```

Esto nos devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
descripcion     dom_descripcion
AA5-55B         5-55
```

El resultado es correcto, pues 5-55 esta contenido dentro de AA5-55B. Sin embargo, datos como 4-789/1 no cumplen con la condicion, pues el primer bloque %[^0-9] evita el 4 que es el primer caracter de la cadena. Entonces, tomando en cuenta la primera condición, buscamos las cadenas que sean exactas con un = y utilizamos ambas condiciones:

```
select *
from ampliatoria amp, dominio dom
where ( amp.descripcion = dom.dom_descripcion
  or amp.descripcion similar to '%[^0-9]' || dom.dom_descripcion || '[^0-9]%')
```

Esto nos devuelve los siguientes resultados:

```
descripcion     dom_descripcion
1-1234          1-1234
AA5-55B         5-55
4-789/1         4-789/1
```

Con esto obtenemos únicamente las cadenas que califican.
El código está en [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7b45b/37) para PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Tu interpretación esta bien. Como respondí en otro comentario, se supone que el campo Amp.descripcion lleva una cadena válida separada por espacios de otros caracteres o solamente la cadena válida. Sin embargo no descarto que existan casos en donde la cadena válida este contenida en otra mayor con caracteres alfabéticos (por ejemplo AB4-567CD).
Tu propuesta es lo que necesitaba. Muy clara y didáctica la explicación. Muchas gracias!